# Capture packets at ethernet port in C language

Tags: c, networking

How to capture packets delivered to my Ethernet port but are discarded because they do not have the same MAC address as my Ethernet card?

I am trying to develop a program in C language. Hence require pointers on how the above can be achieved?

I am trying to do this in Linux.

Comment: What operating system?  Take a look at libpcap http://www.tcpdump.org/

Comment: need to be clear enough while asking a question which lessens the burden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under Linux you may use libpcap library. This is the easiest way. You may also do it "by hand" using appropriate socket type (sock_packet, sock_raw) with promiscuous mode for ethernet interface. Google for "linsniff.c" program if you are looking for example.